# How to increase every next element's translateY on scroll?

Tags: jquery, transform, element

The idea is to make cascade effect of elements that are sticking to top of the window when scrolling. So the question is how to make every next element "bigger" on 20px then its previous same element? [Link on code.](http://codepen.io/NeedHate/pen/PPyjqX)
And my code itself:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $('.text-layer').each(function(i) {
    var distance = $(this).parent().offset().top,
      $window = $(window);
    var increase = (i + 20);

    if ($window.scrollTop() >= distance) {
      $(this).addClass('sticked').css("transform", "translate(0px," + increase + "px)");
    }

    if ($window.scrollTop() <= distance) {
      $(this).removeClass('sticked').css("transform", "translate(0px, 0px)");
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, try changing line 5 to:

```
var increase = i*20;
```

You want each additional element 20, not one pixel lower.

Comment: So that simple... so much to understand... thanks alot!